# OpenCL: How do I copy a GPU array to the CPU?

Tags: opencl

I'm porting some CUDA code to OpenCL. The CUDA code does something like this:

```
// GPU code...
__device__ int counter;
```

```cpp
// CPU code...
int data;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(gpuData, &data, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

What would be the equivalent in OpenCL? Similarly, how would I do this for an array? The only way I know involves allocating an extra buffer, copying to it on the GPU, then reading from it on the CPU.

Comment: In OpenCL, you allocate the (preferably properly aligned) buffer on the host and host memory is allocated as well as memory on the GPU. You don't need to copy the array to the GPU if the kernel(s) are populating it but you can if the GPU is updating it. When you want to process the array in its finished state on the host, an API call copies it into host memory. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`clEnqueueReadBuffer`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadBuffer.html)  command, or with the C++ bindings:

```c
T* host_buffer = nullptr; // host buffer
cl::Buffer device_buffer; // device buffer
cl::CommandQueue cl_queue; // command queue

cl_queue.enqueueReadBuffer(device_buffer, blocking, offset*sizeof(T), length*sizeof(T), (void*)(host_buffer+offset));
```

For a quick overview of OpenCL API calls, see the [OpenCL Reference Card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl30-reference-guide.pdf). If you want to make using OpenCL in C++ way easier and less bloated, see this [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper).